# Image not showing using react styled component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

> I have a problem , my logo image is not show , i am using React js.
> and when i remove my display: flex; property then logo shown with very
> bigger size. so this is the problem , why display: flex is not
> working. ........................here is my
> code...........................

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xUOr.png)

import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

```
const Login = (props) =>{
    return(
        <Container>
            <Nav>
                <a href='/'>
                    <img src='/images/login-logo.svg' alt='' />
                </a>
                <div>
                    <Join>Join Now</Join>
                </div>
            </Nav>
        </Container>
    );
};

const Container = styled.div`
padding: 0px;
`;

const Nav = styled.nav`
max-width: 1128px;
margin: auto;
padding: 12px 0 16px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
position: relative;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-wrap: nowrap;

& > a{
    width: 135px
    height: 34px;
    @media(max-width: 768px){
        padding: 0 5px;
    }
}

`;

const Join = styled.a`
font-size: 16px;
padding: 10px 12px;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 4px;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
margin-right: 12px;
&:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    text-decoration: none;
}
`;


export default Login;
```

Answer (score 1):

its maybe because you forget to `set height and width on image` also `display block on <a>` tag.